# How can I create a parquet file bigger than node's assigned memory?

Tags: apache-drill

I'm trying to create a parquet file from a table stored in mysql. The source contains millions of rows and I get a GC Overhead limit exception after a couple of minutes.

Can apache drill be configured in a way that allows operations to use disk temporarily in case there is no more RAM available?

This were my steps before getting the error:

- Put the mysql jdbc connector inside jars/3rdparty
- Execute sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local"
- Navigate to http://localhost:8047/storage
- Configure a new storage pluggin to connect to mysql
- Navigate to http://localhost:8047/query and execute the following queries
- ALTER SESSION SET `store.format` = 'parquet';
- ALTER SESSION SET `store.parquet.compression` = 'snappy';
- create table dfs.tmp.`bigtable.parquet` as (select * from mysql.schema.bigtable)

Then I get the error and the aplication ends:

Node ran out of Heap memory, exiting.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2149)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3308)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:463)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3032)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2280)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2546)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2504)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1370)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.store.jdbc.JdbcRecordReader.setup(JdbcRecordReader.java:177)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.ScanBatch.(ScanBatch.java:101)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.ScanBatch.(ScanBatch.java:128)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.store.jdbc.JdbcBatchCreator.getBatch(JdbcBatchCreator.java:40)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.store.jdbc.JdbcBatchCreator.getBatch(JdbcBatchCreator.java:33)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.ImplCreator.getRecordBatch(ImplCreator.java:151)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.ImplCreator.getChildren(ImplCreator.java:174)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.ImplCreator.getRecordBatch(ImplCreator.java:131)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.ImplCreator.getChildren(ImplCreator.java:174)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.ImplCreator.getRecordBatch(ImplCreator.java:131)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.ImplCreator.getChildren(ImplCreator.java:174)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.ImplCreator.getRecordBatch(ImplCreator.java:131)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.ImplCreator.getChildren(ImplCreator.java:174)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.ImplCreator.getRootExec(ImplCreator.java:105)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.ImplCreator.getExec(ImplCreator.java:79)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.work.fragment.FragmentExecutor.run(FragmentExecutor.java:230)
        at org.apache.drill.common.SelfCleaningRunnable.run(SelfCleaningRunnable.java:38)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

Check `drill-env.sh` located in `<drill_installation_directory>/conf`

By default values are:

```
DRILL_MAX_DIRECT_MEMORY="8G"
DRILL_HEAP="4G"
```

> The default memory for a Drillbit is 8G, but Drill prefers 16G or more depending on the workload.

*If you have sufficient RAM you can configure it as 16G*

You can read in detail in [Drill's documentation](https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-drill-memory/).

Comment: Do you mean that if I use 16Gb of RAM, drill will use disk if necessary?! I already played with memory parameters but this doesn't solve the question. What if the table is so big it doesn't fit into memory even using 16Gb of memory?

Comment: @DanielSan 16GB RAM has nothing to do with allowance for disk if necessary and all. That was a general suggestion. I did not find in the documentation how to choose on disk. I am looking into it & will let you know if I get something fruitful.